# Set div width to adjust at different resolution

Tags: html, css, width, media-queries

Please check [this link](http://constantcontrast.com/bio/)

The left panel text goes hidden under the center picture if I re-size the browser window.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `.ac-wrapper h2` 30% instead of 50%

```
.ac-wrapper h2 {
    width: 30%;
}
```

**EDITED**

html

```
<div class="ac-device">
    <h2 style="color:#888888">Logical &amp; analytical. <span>Argues till someone <br>just walks away!</span></h2>
    <a href="#" title="What's different about me?"><img src="images/screen1.jpg"></a>
    <h3 class="ac-title">Not enough of an artist to work upon your imagination. Prefers to do stuff freely. Some may not like that, but that's the way I am!</h3>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ac-wrapper h2 {
top: 20%;
width: 100%;
right: 100%;
position: absolute;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 4em;
text-align: center;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: It worked but the left text is now a bit more distant from the center pic than the right text, on different resolutions. I guess that could only be solved by media query. Right?

Comment: Or you could put your `<h2>` tag inside `<div class="ac-device">` just like you have with the other text. But instead of putting left:100% like you did with the other text, put `right:100%; and also `width:100%;. See my EDIT

Comment: This doesn't work in mobile view!

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at Chrome Dev Tools and I don't actually see where at any point styles from within a media query are being loaded. The obvious result you want is that right now that left panel is

```
position: absolute;
width: 50%;
```

and of course at this resolution you want that width to be something smaller. You can change the styles as your title suggests with a media query, but none's firing. Do you mind posting your relevant CSS to see why--if it exists--your mq isn't working?

Judging by the quality of your design I'm guessing you definitely know what a media query is, but just in case:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
  id.class { 
    width: 40%; // or whatever
  }
}
```